# How To remove a marker on google maps api v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want delete a marker, but it doesn't work,
anybody help?
this is my code

```
 GEvent.addListener(map, "dblclick", function()
  {
      deleteMarker(marker, cells);
  }

    );


 function deleteMarker(marker,cells)
  {
    marker.setMap(null);

  }
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is not with `Google Maps v3`.

```
marker.setMap(null);  //CORRECT
```

**function call** has **3 parameters**

```
deleteMarker(marker, cells,true);
```

whereas **function definition** has only **2 parameters**

```
function deleteMarker(marker,cells)
  {
    marker.setMap(null);

  }
```

Comment: @dedyarief Usually happens, this is where `console`(in developer tools) comes into rescue.  Anyway glad to help you :)